# Can't access database from application when SSMS is open

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, ssms

When SSMS is not running I can read and write to my database fine. However when I start up SSMS and browse to my database, my application cannot access that database (Error: Cannot open database "Database Name" requested by the login). However when I disconnect from the server and shut down SSMS I still get the error message from my application. The only way I have found to regain access to my database is to restart my SQL server every time. Please Help

Comment: Looks like you have a limit set on number of database connections, or your database is set to single user mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're running in **single-user** mode.
Make sure you don't have `AttachDBFilename=` in your connectionstring.

`AttachDBFilename` is unique to SQL Express, it spins up a user instance of SQL Express attached to a specific DB Filename for single user mode.  For any production server, you would most likely not be using `AttachDBFilename`.  It is strictly useful for development and experimentation in single-user mode.

**Also :**
You can kill the sleeping sql processes, rather than rebooting sql server.

```
DECLARE @v_spid INT
DECLARE c_Users CURSOR
   FAST_FORWARD FOR
   SELECT SPID
   FROM master..sysprocesses (NOLOCK)
   WHERE spid>50 
   AND status='sleeping' 
   AND DATEDIFF(mi,last_batch,GETDATE())>=60
   AND spid<>@@spid

OPEN c_Users
FETCH NEXT FROM c_Users INTO @v_spid
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
BEGIN
  PRINT 'KILLing '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@v_spid)+'...'
  EXEC('KILL '+@v_spid)
  FETCH NEXT FROM c_Users INTO @v_spid
END

CLOSE c_Users
DEALLOCATE c_Users
```

Comment: It seems that it is the number of database connections is my problem cos it is set to 1 (by default).  However I have no idea how to change it in SSMS. I have set the number of concurrent connections to 0 (i.e. unlimited) but my database still reads as 1 connection. Any advice?

Comment: Can you paste your connection string?

Comment: Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Aidan\Documents\Databases\MSSQL11.AIDAN\MSSQL\DATA\DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30